# Как преобразовать эмодзи в HTML сущность?

Tags: php

Как расшифровать  такой иконки на `&#x1f600;` через PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы выяснить номер символа в юникоде, в PHP можно воспользоваться классом [IntlChar](https://php.net/manual/ru/class.intlchar.php), который доступен в [модуле интернационализации](https://php.net/manual/ru/book.intl.php). Например, в Debian / Ubuntu его нужно дополнительно установить с помощью пакета [php-intl](https://packages.debian.org/stable/php-intl).

```
$html_data = sprintf("&#x%X;", IntlChar::ord(""));
```

Сторока формата хоть и замудрённой получилась, но, думаю, ясно, что она выводит. Впрочем, за подробностями можно обратиться к документации функции [sprintf](https://php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php).

---

Иной подход заключается в использовании особой кодировки под названием HTML-ENTITIES. Просто перекодируем в неё наш символ с помощью функции [mb_convert_encoding](https://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-convert-encoding.php). Правда, гибкость этого варианта несколько ниже - мы не можем управлять видом результирующей HTML-сущности, и она записана десятичным числом. И да, в тех же Debian / Ubuntu из коробки эта функция не работает, нужен пакет [php-mbstring](https://packages.debian.org/stable/php-mbstring).

```
$html_data = mb_convert_encoding("", "html-entities");
```

Comment: Спасибо но без класса можно потому что не удобно использовать. А кстати вы не  знаете хотя бы имя кодировка типа `UTF-8`  и решить через `mb_convert_encoding('', 'unicode', 'UTF-8')`

Comment: Вы правы, дополнил ответ с применением функции mb_convert_encoding

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!